# Rails Bundle Install Not Finding Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundle

I'm having a problem with the rails

```
bundle install
```

command not being able to find a local gemfile.

---

The gem is located here::

```
~/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/mygemname-1.5.0.SNAPSHOT
```

---

I included the gem in my Gemfile.  But when I try to bundle my application, it get this error::

```
Could not find gem 'mygemname-1.5.0.SNAPSHOT' (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

---

I can see the gem sitting on my hardrive, but the bundle install command says it doesn't exist.  Does anybody have any ideas on what may be going on here?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: are you using a ruby manager like rvm or rbenv? what do you get when you run `ruby -v` and `which ruby` at the command line?

Comment: @sixty4bit when I run `ruby -v` I get `ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08) [i386-linux-gnu]`

Comment: Your gem is installed for ruby 2.1.5 but your system is using 2.1.2. Since you have chruby installed, can you try changing to 2.1.5 and see if you can run `bundle install`?

Comment: @sixty4bit Good call.  I ran `chruby ruby-2.1.5` to switch it to the correct ruby version.  Ran `bundle install` on my application.  Same result though.  :(

Comment: what do you get now when you run `which ruby`?

Comment: @sixty4bit I get ruby-2.1.5 on the output now.

Comment: ok. run `gem env` and look for `GEM PATHS`. That will tell you where your Ruby is looking for its gems. Mine looks at `/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0` (because I use rbenv) and `/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.2.0`

Comment: @sixty4bit I'll check when I get back to my desk.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @sixty4bit Ok, so when I run `gem env` I get 2 values for `GEM PATHS`.  First value is `/home/me/.gem/ruby/2.1.5`  Second value is `/home/me/.rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0`

Answer (score 1):

As I can´t comment yet...

I would check:
- Is it really the .gem folder holding the gem or is it symlinked (I am not confident that symlinks work on bundle install)
- Is rbenv or rvm in the game and is the installed gem installed with one of those or globally?

Comment: @sixty4bit and frank ::  I don't currently use rbenv or rvm.  Some time back when I started RoR development, I began using chruby.

Comment: last ideas: (1) Check gemfile for missing comma between gem and version. (2) rename/move gemfile .lock and run bundle install again. (3) what happens if you run gem install mygemname-1.5.0.SNAPSHOT from terminal? (4) what the output of gem list (in terminal?)

Comment: Away from my machine right now.  Will check your suggestions when I get back.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Here are the results.  
1. No missing comma because I didn't supply a gem version  
2. Renamed Gemfile and bundled, same result  
3. `Successfully installed mygemname-1.5.0.SNAPSHOT`  
4. When I run `gem list`, it shows `mygemname-1.5.0.SNAPSHOT` is in the list.

Comment: step 2: I meant the gemfile.LOCK file - check there if the version of your mentioned gem is the very same as you want to install - if not, move the gemfile.LOCK file out of the folder for testing purposes prior running `bundle install` again. (5) Please check output of 'gem environment' in terminal - is your path listed? (6) If you got that gem on git try something like this: `gem 'mygem', :git => 'https://github.com/project/mygem.git', :branch => "yourbranch"` (7) pls post your content/output of gemfile, gemfile.lock, `which ruby`, `ruby -v`, `gem environment`